# Good reasons NOT to design websites with a vector graphics application?

Tags: graphics, svg

All the (web)designers I've known or worked with, used photoshop almost exclusively, and yet, now that I wanna try my hand at web-design for a personal project, I feel compelled to use a vector graphics application (namely Inkscape).

The idea of the *actual design process* just seems more rational with VG, given that I'll be experimenting with laying out and composing graphical 'objects', it seems to make more sense to be able to act upon these as 'wholes', rather than having to deal with the pixels that make them up.

HTML5 and svg seem like another big upside, but I'm worried I may be looking at this the wrong way, due to lack of experience, since I haven't seen anyone designing like this, and resources on the matter are scarce.

So, are there any reasons why this would be a bad idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all. I use Illustrator all of the time for designing websites. It even has slicing features built-in & "save for web" to optimize file sizes.

Colleagues of mine with design backgrounds tend to prefer Illustrator. Those who are technically focused tend to use Photoshop. Some people use both. That's just been my experience. Regardless, you can use anything you like.

SVG hasn't quite caught on like I wanted. Pure vector sites are tough without relying on Flash or Silverlight. I sometimes do hybrid sites, but never with SVG. The support has never been great enough for me to feel comfortable.

Eventually, this will change. It took years for CSS to catch on and gain adequate support. I expect the same will be true for HTML5 & SVG.

Comment: indeed, svg support is still lacking, but the promises are exciting ! have you had any experience with svgweb by any chance ?

Comment: no i haven't. thanks for mentioning it. i'll definitely be giving it a look. :) your ever played with Google's O3D? add an extra dimension and it's quite similar.

Answer (score 1):

no, I've designed sites in Illustrator before. And Photoshop has lots of vector features integrated. The only thing your really need to keep in mind is color palette. And how you will be exporting your files/slices to use in your site. In the end you are exporting to pixel based images.